# How many arguments can theoretically be passed as parameters in c++ functions?

Tags: c++, c, function, arguments

I was wondering if there was a limit on the number of parameters you can pass to a function.

I'm just wondering because I have to maintain functions of 5+ arguments here at my jobs.

And is there a critical threshold in `nbArguments`, talking about performance, or is it linear?

Comment: I don't think it's a performance issue, but rather a readability issue. The magic number that *Code Complete* suggests is `7`, because it's hard for human brain to remember more than 7 units of information at the same time.

Comment: The less the better, maintain your cohesion.

Comment: Theoretically, the limit is the stack size (assuming there's a stack and arguments are pushed there). Other than that, yes, more than 4 starts to get a little bit messy and it's a strong hint that the code needs some refactoring. Of course, there are some exceptions. I guess performance is not a concern here, you will quickly be defeated by code maintenance issues instead of performance issues.

Comment: Can you give me more precision about the definition of this magic number? Is it just arbitrary defined or for readibility purpose as you suggest?

Comment: What are you actually asking? Your title suggest one thing, the body of the question another.

Comment: @FilipeGonçalves: "Theoretically, the limit is the stack size" - the Standard only *requires* an implementation support at least 256, per Annex B "Parameters in one function definition [256].".

Comment: This question is against the rules of this site.

Comment: @TonyD That supports my comment. Supporting *at least* 256 is a lower bound. The upper bound is the stack size.

Comment: There is no hard-and-fast magic number... if you can see a way to better factor the code to be more readable/maintainable/performant or whatever else is important to you, then do so.  Techniques such as passing in multiple values in a single structure, passing containers (arrays, maps, possibly of variants) may help....

Comment: @user2672165 Well thanks for your consideration, but the subject of my question is "is that an objective or subjectiv reason?", so yhea depending of the answer it's breaking rules. But how would I know otherwise...

Comment: @FilipeGonçalves not meaningfully... the upper bound that you can use in your program without compromising portability is 256, but we're now debating implications of your phrasing, and I see no value having quoted the Standard's text and clarified the issue.

Comment: What many of these comments ignore is that many C functions are neither written by nor meant to be read by humans. For instance, I use sympy to generate C code for solving PDEs. It is useful to produce functions with close to 100 parameters. And since the true source code is not those functions, but the python code that creates them, this doesn’t necessarily compromise readability.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Neither the C nor C++ standard places an absolute requirement on the number of arguments/parameters you must be able to pass when calling a function, but the C standard suggests that an implementation should support at least 127 parameters/arguments (§5.2.4.1/1), and the C++ standard suggests that it should support at least 256 parameters/arguments (§B/2).

The precise wording from the C standard is:

> The implementation shall be able to translate and execute at least one program that
>   contains at least one instance of every one of the following limits.

So, one such function must be successfully translated, but there's no guarantee that if *your* code attempts to do so that compilation will succeed (but it probably will, in a modern implementation).

The C++ standard doesn't even go that far, only going so far as to say that:

> The bracketed number following each quantity is recommended as the minimum for that quantity. However, these quantities are only guidelines and do not determine compliance.

As far as what's advisable: it depends. A few functions (especially those using variadic parameters/variadic templates) accept an arbitrary number of arguments of (more or less) arbitrary types. In this case, passing a relatively large number of parameters can make sense because each is more or less independent from the others (e.g., printing a list of items).

When the parameters are more...interdependent, so you're not just passing a list or something on that order, I agree that the number should be considerably more limited. In C, I've seen a few go as high as 10 or so without being *terribly* unwieldy, but that's definitely starting to push the limit even at best. In C++, it's generally enough easier (and more common) to aggregate related items into a `struct` or `class` that I can't quite imagine that many parameters unless it was in a C-compatibility layer or something on that order, where a more...structured approach might force even more work on the user.

In the end, it comes down to this: you're going to either have to pass a smaller number of items that are individually larger, or else break the function call up into multiple calls, passing a smaller number of parameters to each.

The latter can tend to lead toward a stateful interface, that basically forces a number of calls in a more or less fixed order. You've reduced the complexity of a single call, but may easily have done little or nothing to reduce the overall complexity of the code.

In the other direction, a large number of parameters *may* well mean that you've really defined the function to carry out a large number of related tasks instead of one clearly defined task. In this case, finding more specific tasks for individual functions to carry out, and passing a smaller set of parameters needed by each may well reduce the overall complexity of the code.

Comment: Ok, at first I made a distinction between classic parameters and varargs but it doesn't make sense.

Comment: Obligatory Alan Perlis quote: "If you have a procedure with ten parameters, you probably missed some."

Answer (score 8):

It seems like you're veering into subjective territory, considering that C varargs are (usually) passed mechanically the same way as other arguments.

The first few arguments are placed in CPU registers, under most ABIs. How many depends on the number of architectural registers; it may vary from two to ten. In C++, empty classes (such as overload dispatch tags) are usually omitted entirely. Loading data into registers is usually "cheap as free."

After registers, arguments are copied onto the stack. You could say this takes linear time, but such operations are not all created equal. If you are going to be calling a series of functions on the same arguments, you might consider packaging them together as a `struct` and passing that by reference.

To literally answer your question, the maximum number of arguments is an implementation-defined quantity, meaning that the ISO standard requires your compiler manual to document it. The C++ standard also recommends (Annex B) that no implementation balk at less than **256 arguments**, which should be Enough For Anyone™. C requires (§5.2.4.1) support for at least **127 arguments**, although that requirement is normatively qualified such as to weaken it to only a recommendation.

Answer (score 4):

It is not really dirty, sometimes you can't avoid using 4+ arguments while maintaining stability and efficiency. If possible it should be minimized for sake of clarity (perhaps by use of structs), especially if you think that some function is becoming a god construct (function that runs most of the program, they should be avoided for sake of stability). If this is the case, functions that take larger numbers of arguments are pretty good indicators of such constructs.